# Where can I get to by ferry from Aberdeen Pier in Hong Kong?

Tags: public-transport, hong-kong, ferries

According to [this website](http://www.ferry.com.hk/eng/service.htm), there are direct ferries from [Aberdeen Pier, Hong Kong](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Aberdeen+Pier/@22.2483429,114.1507773,17z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x34040002549cc079:0x46fa4b210fc553db!8m2!3d22.2473693!4d114.1524989) to Sok Wu Wan on the Lamma Island. Are there ferries from Aberdeen to other places? For example, to Mui Wo (or other parts of the Lantau Island), or to Central, or to the Kowloon Peninsula?

Comment: I assume you mean Aberdeen Pier Macau. Because you can get a ferry to The Shetland Isles from Aberdeen.

Comment: I mean Aberdeen Pier in Hong Kong. I assumed this is clear from the "hong-kong" tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go a lot of places from Aberdeen Pier in Hong Kong, though they are mainly outlying islands.

According to the Transport Department in Hong Kong, there are two franchised/licensed ferry line that departs from Aberdeen Promenade that gets you to Lamma Island:

1. [Aberdeen - Yung Shue Wan via Pak Kok Tsuen](https://www.td.gov.hk/en/transport_in_hong_kong/public_transport/ferries/service_details/index.html#o09)
2. [Aberdeen - Sok Kwu Wan (via Mo Tat)](https://www.td.gov.hk/en/transport_in_hong_kong/public_transport/ferries/service_details/index.html#o10)

Furthermore, according to [Traway Travel Limited](http://www.traway.com.hk/ferry/), they operate two more routes (in addition to 1.) from Aberdeen as of 2019:

3. Aberdeen - Stanley / Po Toi Island
4. Aberdeen - Cheung Chau ([Alternate link](http://tsuiwahferry.com/en/ferry-service-hong-kong-routes/aberdeen-cheung-chau/))

There are also [two river crossings (kaito) routes](https://www.td.gov.hk/en/transport_in_hong_kong/public_transport/ferries/kaito_services_map/service_details/index_t.html#k14) between Aberdeen Promenade and Ap Lei Chau (main street), and a ferry service that gets you to the [Jumbo Kingdom](https://www.jumbo.com.hk/en/transportation.html), a pair of floating seafood restaurant nearby.

---

The OP also asked:

> Are there ferries from Aberdeen to [...] Mui Wo (or other parts of the Lantau Island), or to Central, or to the Kowloon Peninsula?

As of 2019, no, at least not directly:

- Mui Wo is served by ferries to/from Central, Cheung Chau and Ping Chau only ([Link](https://hkferry.fandom.com/zh/wiki/%E6%A2%85%E7%AA%A9%E6%B8%A1%E8%BC%AA%E7%A2%BC%E9%A0%AD) to the ferry wiki in Hong Kong, Chinese only);
- Central is better connected via minibuses; and
- By extension, Kowloon Peninsula, which is further to Aberdeen in Central, is too far to make travelling by boat practical.